# Редактор кода с лучшим интерфейсом и подсветкой синаксиса

Tags: windows, редактор-текста, ide

Посоветуйте хороший редактор кода (пусть даже на английском) с подсветкой синтаксиса (html, css, js, jq, ajax, php как минимум). Нужно чтобы он очень хорошо выглядел. Пример такого редактора на Mac - Coda 2

Comment: Лучше используйте полноценную IDE типа [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/index.html).

Comment: Ужасный интерфейс у него.

Comment: > Ужасный интерфейс у него.

to whom how... Линейка вообще IDEA считается очень user-friendly.

Comment: Вообще "Редактор кода с лучшим интерфейсом и подсветкой синаксиса" -- это vim. Как говорит Владимир Вольфович "однозначно". К его интерфейсу могут быть претензии, но работающего "лучше" нет и пока не предвидится.

Comment: > Ужасно бесит интерфейс, что мешает работать.

Интересно, а что именно не нравится?

Comment: > html, css, js, jq, ajax, php

интересно, а как должна работать подсветка jq и ajax

Comment: > Ужасно бесит интерфейс, что мешает работать.

Только я подумал про танцора и яйца?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sublime text 2

http://www.sublimetext.com/2

Answer (score 4):

Для html/js/css и сопутствующих вещей типа haml и coffeescript есть отличная IDE [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). Стоит всего 50$. Отрабатывает эти деньги по-полной.

UPD0.
В качестве хорошего универсального редактора могу еще порекомендовать [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2). Тоже не сильно дорогой.

Comment: Как альтернатива notepad++ - плюсую Sublime Text, кстати его вовсе не обязательно покупать :) Единственное что, если не купишь, изредка будет выскакивать окошко вида "купи меня", т.е., если грубо, то Sublime Text условно платный.

WebStorm чудесная IDE, но из разряда "тяжеловесов"

Comment: >WebStorm чудесная IDE, но из разряда "тяжеловесов"

по сравнению с VS он для меня как блокнот

под делу, я за продукцию JetBrains

Answer (score 2):

Как бесплатную IDE могу посоветовать [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org). Отличная подсветка кода, автозавершение для всех языков, умение работать с FTP, SFTP, SSH, системами контроля версий (в базе уже идет поддержка Git, Mercurial). Расширяется дополнениями.

Если что-то полегче, то [PHP Designer](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php) весьма неплох, но за него нужно платить.

Comment: я тоже за нетбинс

Comment: Согласен, NetBeans с расширениями для PHP очень даже ничего.